# Поймать ошибку в функции

Tags: python, pandas, type-error

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть код:

```
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
df2 = pd.read_excel('NEW_ОЭК 2019-2020.xlsx')
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='DESKTOP-IPUFB3P')
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=0.5)
#geocode = partial(geolocator.geocode, language="ru")
for index,string in   enumerate(df2['Address'][480:]): 
    print(string)
    print(index)
    if (string == np.nan) or (string is None):
        index+=1
        print("Fack")
        continue
    else:
        try:
            location = geocode(string)
            print(location)
            print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
      
        except:
            print("Что-то пошло не так")
```

который прекрасно ловит ошибку, НО когда я хочу тоже самое написать в функции:

```
from functools import partial
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='DESKTOP-IPUFB3P')
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=0.5)


#geocode = partial(geolocator.geocode, language="ru")
# def geopy (address):
#     if address == None:
#         return 'Неточный адрес'
#     else:
#         location = geocode(string)
#         print(location)
#         print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
#         return location.latitude, location.longitude
def geopy (address):
    try:
        location = geocode(string)
        print(location)
        print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    
    except:
        return 'error:' + str(address)        
       #         location = geocode(address)
#         print(address)
#         print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
#         return location.latitude, location.longitude
def mistake(address):
    if address == None:
        return 'Неточный адрес'
    else:
        return 'Error'
    
df = pd.read_excel('NEW_ОЭК 2019-2020.xlsx')

df['Lat and Long'] = df['Address'].apply(geopy)

df.to_excel('NEW_ОЭК4 2019-2020.xlsx')
df.head()
```

То ничего не работает! Что делать?

Comment: а что значит "ничего не работает"? Можете привести в вопросе небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример данных?

Comment: @MaxU данные те же самые, что и в предыдущем вопросе, а результат функции я показала на скрине

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) ;)

Comment: а где в вашей функции for index,string и далее ? целого куска нехватает ?  location = geocode(string)   откуда string берётся ?

Comment: @Интик я не заметила этот недочет, сейчас запустила функцию, вроде пошла в обработку)))